# Is it possible to style military bases only with the new Google Maps v3 styled map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coding-style, google-maps-api-3

Already asked on Google groups, not getting any responses...

I was playing with the [Google Maps v3 style wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) and noticed that if you set a style for poi only, it will set the style for military bases. Unfortunately, it also sets styles for all other points of interest.

Anyone know if there is a way to style military bases only? poi.military didn't work... but there's no documentation of that either.

Obviously, this would be only for publicly acknowledged military bases already on the Google maps - for security reasons. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Does `poi.government` work? I'm not sure where to look for a military base to verify this.